# Blocking unauthorized tcp client

Tags: c#, security, tcp, handshake

I'm new to C# and I was wondering if it's possible to have a mechanism to check authorization similar to how a TCP client sends a decrypted password in its handshake packet.  If not, how can I prevent unauthorized clients from connecting to my TCP server?

The code below shows where I accept each client and keep them in a `TCPClientObject` Array for further use later:

```
private void startTcpClientAccept()
{
    while (true)
    {
        TCPClientObject temp = new TCPClientObject();
        temp.setIndex(availableIndexes.Dequeue());
        temp.setClient(server.AcceptTcpClient());

        //I need the check mecanism here. before receiving any messages
        clientList[temp.getIndex()] = temp;

        Console.WriteLine("GSM Client is accepted");
     }
}
```

Basically, the problem is anyone can connect to server and this may create some security problems further.

Comment: This question seems a bit broad. Perhaps you could ask about a specific security implementation?

Comment: I've been searching for awhile but I couldn't fine a way to secure connection before or during accepting TCP client.

Comment: TCP doesn't really provide a way to do what you want - instead, you'll need to design your protocol (on top of TCP) to manually authenticate

Comment: Maybe your looking for something like TLS, VPN, SSL, SSH, etc.?